# Find integers $x,y$ such that $21x + 13y = 1$

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

Given  Bézout's identity, how do I find the $x,y$, I already performed the euclidean algorithm. So.

- 21 = 1 * 13 + 8
- 13 = 1 * 8 + 5
- 8 = 1 * 5 + 3
- 5 = 1 * 3 + 2
- 3 = 1 * 2 + 1
- 2 = 1 * 1 + 1
- 1 = 1 * 1 + 0

I am not sure how to find the x,y though I tried starting from 1 = 2 - 1 and then substituting
2 as 3 - 1 and so on but I wasn't getting anywhere I know I need to somehow get 21*some number + 13 * some number but I am confused on how to start.

Comment: why did my question get downvoted? can I know so that next time I can provide better questions?

Comment: with consecutive Fibonacci numbers, the needed coefficients are also consecutive Fibonacci,

Answer (score 3):

Use the *extended Euclidean algorithm*: it relies on the fact that  all remainders in the Euclidean algorithm, satisfy a Bézout's identity, and corresponding coefficients can be computed recursively.

\begin{array}{rrrl}
r_i&x_i&y_i &q_i\\ \hline
21&1&0 \\
13&0&1&1 \\ \hline
8&1&-1&1\\5&-1&2&1 \\
3&2&-3&1 \\
2&-3&5&1 \\  \hline
1&\color{red}5&\color{red}{-8}
\end{array}

Comment: How does this chart work, it looks simpler to write.

Comment: You simply rewrite the $i$-th division: $r_{i-1}=q_ir_i+r_{i+1}$ as $r_{i+1}=r_{i-1}-q_ir_i$ and observe that by lienarity the same relation is valid for the coefficients: $x_{i+1}=x_{i-1}-q_ix_i ,\enspace y_{i+1}=y_{i-1}-q_iy_i$.

Answer (score 2):

(Using the extended Euclidean algorithm, not Fibonacci identities)

$1=3-2=3-(5-3)=2\cdot3-5=2\cdot(8-5)-5=2\cdot8-3\cdot5=2\cdot8-3\cdot(13-8)=5\cdot8-3\cdot13=5\cdot(21-13)-3\cdot13=5\cdot21-8\cdot13$

Comment: Thanks for correcting the typo in my answer!